# Сервер с серым ip

Tags: ip, openserver

Как создать сервер на компе с серым IP? Я понимаю что можно через VPN но не знаю как именно

---

Вот добавил. Но он не запускается говорит что сервер может быть только на 127.0.0.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

введите сюда описание изображенияВот скриншот пожалуйста............
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Этим я могу как-нибудь воспользоваться?
[image]

[image]

Comment: В чем у тебя проблема ? Пробовал что я предлагал?

Comment: На no-ip нужен белый ip

Comment: Если хотите дополнить вопрос - воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом. Форма ответов тут только для постов, которые содержат в себе решение проблемы.

Comment: Комп открывает, телефон нет

Comment: с телефона нет.

Comment: Папку с сайтом обзави как хочешь только не ип адрес и не localhost . В настройках домена укажи имя домена и путь к сайту (имя только не ип и не localhost ), в настройках Алиса исходный домен 192.168.1.100 конечный который ты придумал в доменах